# Persia will completely annihilate Edom which will cause moshiach to come

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-gemara, army-military-war, ymoth-hamoshiach, persia

I heard that in a passage in the Talmud it says Persia will completely annihilate Edom and the rest of the world which will then spur about moshiach' arrival,  the Yalkut Shimoni (Yeshaya 60:499), records the following amazing but scary prophecy regarding the events that will unfold just prior to the Messianic Era: “Rabbi Yitzchak said: The year in which the King Messiah reveals himself [to all of mankind], all the nations of the world will be fighting with each other. The King of Paras [Persia] will fight with the King of Arabia, and the King of Arabia will go to Aram [Syria] to seek counsel from them. The King of Paras will [attempt to] destroy the entire world, and all the nations of the world will be screaming and confused and falling on their faces, and they will experience pains like those of a woman giving birth. The Jewish people will also be screaming and confused, and will say, ‘To where shall we come and go? To where shall we come and go?’. And G-d will say to them, ‘My children - don’t be afraid - for all that I have done, I only did for your sake. Why are you afraid – the time for your redemption has come!, my question is what weapon of choice will Persia use to bring about this result.

Comment: You might considering citing or hyperlinking specific sources to help the community address your question. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed in the [revision history](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/61859/revisions) that someone else added the citation of Talmud to your question. Is that the right one? I ask because the picture says something *slightly* different than what your question does, and totally changes your question cc @havarka

Comment: Specifically, this quote doesn't say that the Persians will *cause* moshiach to come, but rather that they will be the ones in charge until the end, at which point they will be toppled by Rome.

Comment: Persia is modern-day Iran, FWIW.

Comment: That picture doesn't look like the typical layout or font used in Talmud. Looks like it may be a commentary (possibly _Tosafos_) on the Talmud.

Comment: it is gemore, I even wrote it where is it from :)

Comment: @havarka the first line is the gemara. The rest of the paragraph is in fact Tosafos as msh210 correctly guessed.

Comment: The correct translation of that line in the gemara is '  their kingdom will continue (lit. stretch) until Moshiach comes.

Comment: give me a break gemore/tojsfojs rashi, it is in the same book :)

Comment: @shokhet I heard Persia will topple Rome

Comment: The answer is that Persia was, at the time of the gemara, not just a random nation "out of all the nations in the world". They were an empire, competing with Rome. See here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthian_Empire
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_Empire

Comment: I edited your question -- please ask the question you intend to ask if you expect relevant answers.

Comment: All this needs is a bit of modern political knowledge. Persia is  Iran, Edom is the Western world. Iran is on the path to a nuclear bomb. Kinda apocalyptic, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that your edits to the question are fair to the existing answers. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/5323 for more info...but I think you should roll back your edits

Comment: @Shokhet None were upvoted, so its fine.

Comment: @mevaqesh Perhaps none were up voted because the question changed http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61859/persia-will-completely-annihilate-edom-which-will-cause-moshiach-to-come/61883#comment170359_61883

Comment: @Shokhet Not sure what you mean. I was saying that the OP can be changed until it invalidates upvoted answers. At the time it was changed, I don't think there were any upvoted answers.

Comment: Actually i would like to make a correction, the more accurate non censored versions say Edom instead of Aram. I guess the Franciscan monks didn't like being called what they really are.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any passage in the Talmud that says Persia will completely annihilate Edom and the rest of the world will then spur about the arrival of Moshiach.

I think whoever you heard this from may be mistaken and the source that he is misunderstanding is [Yoma 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.10a.10?lang=bi) where there is recorded a machloket over whether Rome will fall into the hands of Persia or Persia will fall into the hands of Rome:

> אָמַר רַבָּה בַּר בַּר חָנָה אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי
> יְהוּדָה בְּרַבִּי אִלְעַאי: עֲתִידָה רוֹמִי שֶׁתִּפּוֹל בְּיַד
> פָּרַס, קַל וָחוֹמֶר: וּמָה מִקְדָּשׁ רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁבְּנָאוּהוּ בְּנֵי
> שֵׁם וְהֶחְרִיבוּהוּ כַּשְׂדִּיִּים — נָפְלוּ כַּשְׂדִּיִּים בְּיַד
> פָּרְסִיִּים. מִקְדָּשׁ שֵׁנִי שֶׁבְּנָאוּהוּ פָּרְסִיִּים
> וְהֶחְרִיבוּהוּ רוֹמִיִּים — אֵינוֹ דִּין שֶׁיִּפְּלוּ רוֹמִיִּים
> בְּיַד פָּרְסִיִּים?
>
> Similarly, Rabba bar bar Ḥana said that Rabbi
> Yoḥanan said in the name of Rabbi Yehuda, son of Rabbi Elai: Rome is
> destined to fall into the hands of Persia. This is derived by means of
> an a fortiori inference: Just as the First Temple, that the
> descendants of Shem built it and the Chaldeans destroyed it, and in
> turn the Chaldeans, ruled by Belshazzar, fell to Persians, ruled by
> Darius the Mede and his son-in-law Cyrus the Persian; the Second
> Temple, that the Persians built it and the Romans destroyed it, is it
> not right that the Romans will fall into the hands of the Persians?
>
> אָמַר רַב: עֲתִידָה פָּרַס שֶׁתִּפּוֹל בְּיַד רוֹמִי. אֲמַרוּ לֵיהּ
> רַב כָּהֲנָא וְרַב אַסִּי לְרַב: בָּנוֹיֵי בְּיַד סָתוֹרֵי?! אֲמַר
> לְהוּ: אִין, גְּזֵירַת מֶלֶךְ הִיא. אִיכָּא דְאָמְרִי, אֲמַר (לֵיהּ):
> אִינְהוּ נָמֵי הָא קָא סָתְרִי בֵּי כְנִישְׁתָּא.
>
> In contrast, Rav
> said: Persia is destined to fall into the hands of Rome. Rav Kahana
> and Rav Asi, Rav’s students, said to Rav: The builders will fall into
> the hands of the destroyers? Is that justice? He said to them:
> Although it seems unjust, yes, that is the King’s decree. Some say
> that he said this to them: They, too, are destroyers of synagogues,
> and they are no better than the Romans.

From here we see that according to the opinion that Rome will fall into the hands of Persia the weapon of choice that Persia will use is their merit that they built the Second Temple whereas Rome destroyed it.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yakov and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!